# When I hover on Button to increase its size , the elements under it move to down

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have in my HTML page a button , if i hover on it , its size increased , and it's working , but the problem , when i hover on it , the elements which are under it , move down , like a shifting or something

HTML

```
<td><input name="newEx" type="button" id="newEx" style="background- color:green ; color:white"  align ="left" value="مسألة جديدة"  onclick="randomArray(6,1,99)"height="30px" width="85px" /> 

<input name="sol" type="button"  id="sol" style="background-color:#606 ; color:#FFF  " align="left" value="الحل النموذجي" onclick="solution()"  height="30px" width="85px"/></td>
```

CSS

```
    #newEx:hover{ 
 width:100px;
 height:40px;}

    #sol:hover{ 
 width:100px;
 height:40px;}
```

under these two button , there is a div, after hovering on one of them, this div go down 
 how to solve this problem?

Comment: The height of the button is getting bigger which would push the other elements underneath down, or are you talking about something else?

Comment: The element that is being pushed down should have its position to be set to fixed.

Comment: yes, you are right , 
**The height of the button is getting bigger which would push the other elements underneath down,**

Comment: i will try now  , @InfinitePrime

Comment: it didn't work, the whole page changed @InfinitePrime

Comment: Depending on how much bigger you're making the button.. You could reduce the `margin` on `hover`?

Comment: can i use 'margin' instead 'height' or 'width'? @Jay

Comment: @OraibAboRob I mean.. Say your buttons height is growing from `100px` to `110px`. You could reduce the `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` on it by `5px` to counteract the effect on surrounding elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create a content div and put buttons inside div.

HTML:

```
<div class="content-div">
    <input name="newEx" type="button" id="newEx" align ="left" value="مسألة جديدة" onclick="randomArray(6,1,99)" height="30px" width="85px" />

    <input name="sol" type="button" id="sol" align="left" value="الحل النموذجي" onclick="solution()"  height="30px" width="85px"/>
</div>

<div style="width: 100%; height: 100px; background-color: red;"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.content-div {
    position: relative;
    height: 40px;
}
#newEx {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
}
#newEx, #sol {
    margin-top: 5px;
}
#sol {
    background-color:#606;
    color:#FFF  
}
#newEx:hover, #sol:hover { 
    width:100px;
    height:40px;
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aitorrodriguez/tgL7r725/2/

Something like this should fix your problem ;)

Comment: do you mean to put the buttons on div?

Comment: I try it , but i replace absolute with static , Thank u very much

Comment: Oh , I can't because i have less than 15 reputation .

Answer (score 1):

@chrona is right, also using position for hove is not a good practice. Try the below code. I have modified your code a little, Hope this works for you.

**CSS**

```
input{
    background-color:green; 
    color:white;
    width:100px;
    height:40px;
    font-size: 12px;
    border: 0;

}
input#sol{
    background-color:#606 ; color:#FFF
}
#newEx:hover{ 
    background-color:#606 ; 
    font-size: 13px;
 }

#sol:hover{ 
    background-color:green;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<td>
    <input name="newEx" type="button" id="newEx"   align ="left" value="مسألة جديدة"  onclick="randomArray(6,1,99)"/> 
    <input name="sol" type="button"  id="sol" align="left" value="الحل النموذجي" onclick="solution()"  />
</td>
```

Comment: Thanxs very much, i will see :)